# Determine any points of discontinuity a function

Tags: limits, continuity

The problem is: Determine any points of discontinuity of the function described by $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2,  & \text{if $x^2+y^2 \le 1$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x^2+y^2 > 1$}
\end{cases}$$

My results

Attempt #1:

Because $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, what I did is represent y through x, $y(x) = \sqrt{(1-x^2)}$ while x approaches one.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1, y \to \sqrt{(1-x^2)}} x^2+y^2 = \lim\limits_{x \to 1} x^2 + 1 - x^2 = 1$

If we take $x^2+y^2 > 1$, the limit would be zero, thus the there is discontinuity at $x^2+y^2 = 1$

Is this approach correct?

Attempt #2:

Approaching from within the region where $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, we can make the change $x \to cost(t)$ and $y \to sin(t)$, as t approaches the boundary.

$\lim\limits_{x \to cos(t), y \to \sin(t)} x^2+y^2 = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} cos^2(t)+sin^2(t) = 1$

Approaching from outside the region where $x^2+y^2 > 1$, we can make the change $x \to 2cost(t)$ and $y \to 2sin(t)$, as t approaches the boundary.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2cos(t), y \to 2sin(t)} x^2+y^2 = \lim\limits_{t \to 0} 4cos^2(t)+4sin^2(t) = 4$

Since the two limits do not agree, there is a discontinuity at the points on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$

Can someone confirm if both attempts have the correct steps?

Comment: I haven't read the approaches, but anything involving limits is probably already overkill. The function is composed of two polynomials, namely $(x, y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$ and $(x, y) \mapsto 0$. We know each is continuous everywhere. Therefore, the only points of discontinuity have to lie where the transition occurs: $S = \{ (x, y): x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$. On this set, the first function is equal to 1 while the second is equal to 0. Therefore, $S$ contains all points of discontinuity.